# Want download of entire Photo Stream and or Camera Roll from iPhone4S running iOS 5.1.1 to Win 7 Enterprise SP1?

Tags: iphone, windows, photo-stream

How can I force download of entire Photo Stream and or Camera Roll to iCloud from iPhone4S running iOS 5.1.1 (9B206) to Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit?

iCloud folders on the Win 7 machine are empty and none of the photos I want are "new".
If I place photos in the iCloud Upload folder they are uploaded to the Photo Stream on the phone and then on the Win7 Photo Stream folder, but how can I get all the old ones to download?  I'm considering using the App "WiFi Photo Transfer" but would prefer using existing iCloud.  Cannot tell if I have iCloud 2 or not.

I tried carpetflyer's suggestion of turning Photo Stream off and on in iCloud and the result was 2 new Albums in my phone, Photo Library with my most recent 6 photos, and My Photo Stream which was empty.  The My Photo Stream on my Win7 computer downloaded the 6 most recent photos in the Photo Stream album (the contents of Photo Library) and that's all that gets downloaded.  There are 353 others in my Photo Stream album that I'd also like.  I need help.  Anyone tried the "WiFi Photo Transfer" App?

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell...

- Connect iPhone to iCloud.
- Configure PC to connect to same iCloud account.
- Select Photo Stream and click the Options button.
- Configure your Upload and Download Folder, and Select the Photo Streams you want to sync.
- Your photos should start to sync at this point; check My Computer | Libraries | Pictures.

This setup works for me on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old and maybe you found a solution by now, but after much frustration trying to do similar tasks as you posted in your question, I went and purchased iPhone Backup Extractor from http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/ and I couldnt be happier!!   I have no affiliation with that software or company.  I just wanted to let you know how much it helped me.